# Monitoring external event job progress using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

How can I make an external job appear on a Jenkins dashboard more like a native Jenkins job, specifically including a progress 'bar'?

I've come across https://plugins.jenkins.io/external-monitor-job but this only appears to provide a way to say

> My jobs has finished with this console output and this result code.

I would also like to see things such as current progress. Or to put it another way, I'd like my external job to be able to appear on something like https://kj187.github.io/dashing-jenkins_job/ in a similar manner to a native Jenkins job.

So is it possible to push more data than the external-monitor-job suggests?

Comment: So, let me get this right. You have an external process, for example a database migration with their start and end time (5 min for instance). Do you need a Jenkins ui interface to show this 5 min duration as if there was a native job https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/thumbnail/33232/_thumb_33232.png  ??

Comment: Pretty much yes!  Clearly this, and the Jenkins dashboard widgets, have some idea of the time (or perhaps number of steps?) that a job will take and seem able to display progress. Looks like the e-m-j plugin creates a 'run' object in 'completed' state so should be possible to change states but how is the webpage 'instantiated'?

Comment: My concern is about how show the dashboard : Building some job and show the dashboard as the result or something like pipeline dashboard plugin : https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Stage+View+Plugin

Comment: I think there is not a plugin to your requirement, but a new one could be developed to allow to jenkins managers , monitoring external resources.

Comment: My thoughts exactly but I'm struggling to get from the simple 'hello world' Jenkins plugin example to something that can create a listening HTTP socket. 
 It would be good to find the source for a plugin that actually interacted with the outside world!

Comment: Hi Paul. If my answer does not satisfy you , contact me (https://jrichardsz.github.io) to create some plugin.

Comment: I think I'm getting the hang of it.  Having followed the Stapler code around I ended up back at things like RootAction, ExtensionPoint and @Extension.  Going to take another look at the Jenkins docs tonight to see if I know know enough to understand them :-).

Answer (score 0):

Create a free style job and monitor the external process (print logs etc.) in the free style job - read the logs till logical conclusion in the freestyle job

Comment: Freestyle looks interesting but when I tell you that the external job is actually a GitLab CI process I suspect this would not work.  Since GitLab seems to have few dashboard like features, but Jenkins is 'plug-in rich' I am wondering whether extending the function of the external-monitor-jobs plugin would allow me to use Jenkins as a 'front end dashboard' for GitLab.

Answer (score 0):

## What about pipeline view plugin?

[image]

Steps will be:

## v1 (manual way)

- create a job called **monitoring_external_process** inside pipeline view. This job performs a kind of ping looking the end of your process.
- start your external process in a separate way.
- go to jenkins **monitoring_external_process** job and press **build**.
- a progress bar will be showed until the end of your external process.

## v2 (automatic way)

- create a job called **monitoring_external_process** inside pipeline view. This job performs a kind of ping looking the end of your process.
- configure a webhook trigger or remote build for this job. This enable a public url to invoke the jenkins job. (See link reference #2)
- configure your external process to perform an htttp request to the public url.
- start your external process in a separate way.
- Automatically your job will be started and progress bar will be showed until the end of your external process.

References:

- (1) https://code-maven.com/jenkins-pipeline-hello-world
- (2) https://jrichardsz.github.io/devops/devops-with-git-and-jenkins-using-webhooks

Comment: Looks interesting but if I read the second article correctly you're using Git as the code management and Jenkins as the CI tool.  In my case I have inherited Git and GitLab CI systems that work but people would like a dashboard 'just like Jenkins' for these jobs (we have some older systems that still use Jenkins in the manner you describe). So the idea is that Jenkins is purely a monitor of builds on GitLab CI.

Comment: uhmmm. Do you want a dashboard like jenkins but without jenkins?

Comment: Exactly!  People like GitLab CI but the first comment is always 'where's the dashboard that looks like Jenkins' (we really only need the build status - I'm not going to be controlling the GitLab CI from Jenkins) so using Jenkins as a front end seems like the simplest option.  Of course having GitLab catch up would be better and hopefully it will but for now I'm enjoying learning a little Java and sorting out Jenkins extension points ;-).